# Is it a retain cycle if I use a ivar inside block?

Tags: ios

I have some idea about retain cycle. If I use self.variable inside block. It is said that I let the view controller retains the block and the block retain the self.property that retain to self. So the retain cycle occurs.However ,if I declare a instance variable , and I use it inside the block , is it a retain cycle? If YES, how to solve the problem?

The code is :

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *phone;
}
@end
-(void)example
{

    [self.varble ^block
     {
         phone=@"abc";// a retain cycle?
     }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will still retain self

You should either reference the ivar through a weak instance:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *phone;
}
@end
-(void)example
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.varble ^block
     {
         typeof(self) self = weakSelf;
         self->phone=@"abc";// a retain cycle?
     }];

}
```

Or if you weren't changing the value (just simply using it), copy the value of the ivar into a local variable:

```
@interface ViewController (){
    NSString *phone;
}
@end
-(void)example
{
    NSString *phoneValue = [phone copy]; // the copy is optional, but good practice
    [self.varble ^block
     {
         [phoneValue someMethod];
     }];

}
```

Comment: thanks..you mean I can use weakSelf->phone=@"abc"; inside block and there is no retain cycle..Am I right?

Comment: @seguedestination that's right, because you're using it through the weak variable it wont be retained by the block